# Apply pandas to_numeric() to a some columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe such as:

```
page            source_url      count   yes   no   ii  dk

google.com      youtube.com        3      0    0    1   2

facebook.com    whatsapp.com       3      0    0    1   2

microsoft.com   stackoverflow.com  3      0    0    1   2
```

I want to apply `pd.to_numeric` on the last 4 columns only.

I tried doing :

```
df['count'] = pd.to_numeric(df['count'])
df['yes'] = pd.to_numeric(df['yes'])
df['no'] = pd.to_numeric(df['no'])
df['ii'] = pd.to_numeric(df['i'])
df['dk'] = pd.to_numeric(df['dk'])
```

But the first line keeps giving me:

```
ValueError at /
Unable to parse string "<bound method Series.count of page          https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/trump-suicid...
source_url    https://www.facebook.com/candace.witte/posts/1...
count                                                         0
Name: 7909, dtype: object>" at position 0
```

How can I use `to_numeric()` on some columns of a dataframe?

Comment: Did you perhaps use `df.count` in your code, either currently or in a prior function or iteration, to assign to the `count` column? It looks like you may have overwritten something in your namespace with the dataframe.count function signature, based on `string <bound method Series.count...`

Comment: no I didnt use ```.count``` anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your column `count` has at least one non-numeric value, in this case one that starts with "bound method Series.count...". To turn errors into `nan` you could do the following:

```
df['count'] =  df.count.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

If more columns have the same problem, you could do the same for them

Comment: Thx man. I checked the csv and there was an issue with the script that generated it. I fixed it and now the code works